# JWT token access from header

Tags: json, laravel, jwt, token

I am working with JWT token to make API in Laravel, I want to Make CRUD operation, I already test my API in Postman.

Now the issue is that I want to implement it via Laravel blade views, in postman I can set Authorization Bearer in header, How would I do that in Laravel application? Not in Postman, in short I want to set header, so I can access token in each every request.

Controller:

```
<?php

class NewController extends Controller
{

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        $token = auth()->attempt($credentials);
        return $this->createNewToken($token);
    }

    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|between:2,100',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:100|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(array(
                "status" => false,
                "errors" => $validator->errors()
            ), 400);
        }

        $user = User::create(array_merge(
            $validator->validated(),
            ['password' => bcrypt($request->password)]
        ));

        return response()->json([
            'status' => true,
            'message' => 'User successfully registered',
            'user' => $user
        ], 201);
    }

    public function refresh()
    {
        return $this->createNewToken(auth()->refresh());
    }

    public function userProfile()
    {
        return $this->getAuthenticatedUser();
    }

    public function me()
    {
        $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
        return response()->json(array($user), 400);
    }

    protected function createNewToken($token)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60,
            'user' => auth()->user()
        ]);
    }

    public function getAuthenticatedUser()
    {
        try {

            if (!$user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
                return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
            }

        } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {

            return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());

        } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {

            return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());

        } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {

            return response()->json(['token_absent'], $e->getStatusCode());

        }

        return response()->json(compact('user'));
    }
}
```

Routes:

```
    'prefix' => 'auth',
], function ($router) {
    Route::post('login', [App\Http\Controllers\NewController::class, 'login'])->name('apisignin');
    Route::post('getauth', [App\Http\Controllers\NewController::class, 'getAuthenticatedUser'])->name('getAuthenticatedUser');
    Route::post('userProfile', [App\Http\Controllers\NewController::class, 'userProfile']);
    Route::post('me', [App\Http\Controllers\NewController::class, 'me']);
});
```

Comment: Are you using something like `Vue` or `React` in your Blade views?

Comment: No, I am using Laravel Blade View.

Comment: Tokens are used to provide authorisation for `API`s. If all you're doing is serving blade views, then you do not need to use a `JWT`.

Comment: Okay, Thank You.